# Updating AngularJS Modules & Routing

Tags: angularjs, module, routes

Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="groceryListApp">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
          </span> 
        Grocery List
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container" ng-view>

  </div>

<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('groceryListApp', ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "views/groceryList.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })

    .when("/addItem",{
       templateUrl: "views/addItem.html",
        controller:  "GroceryListItemController"

      })

    .when("/addItem/edit/:id",{
       templateUrl: "views/addItem.html",
        controller:  "GroceryListItemController"

      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"

      })
});



app.service("GroceryService",function(){

var groceryService = {};

groceryService.groceryItems = [
    {
      id:1,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'milk',
      date: '2017-10-01'
    },
    {
      id:2,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cookies',
      date: '2017-10-02'
    },
    {
      id:3,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'ice cream',
      date: '2017-10-03'
    },
    {
      id:4,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'potatoes',
      date: '2017-10-04'
    },
    {
      id:5,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'cereal',
      date: '2017-10-05'
    },
    {
      id:6,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'bread',
      date: '2017-10-06'
    },
    {
      id:7,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'eggs',
      date: '2017-10-07'
    },
    {
      id:8,
      completed: true,
      itemName: 'tortillas',
      date: '2017-10-08'
    }
  ];

  groceryService.findById = function(id){
    for( var item in groceryService.groceryItems){

        if(groceryService.groceryItems[item].id === id) {
          console.log(groceryService.groceryItems[item]);
            return groceryService.groceryItems[item];
      }
    }
  };

  groceryService.getNewId = function(){

    if(groceryService.newId){
      groceryService.newId++;
      return groceryService.newId;

    }else{
      var maxId = _.max(groceryService.groceryItems,function(entry){return entry.id;})

      groceryService.newId = maxId.id + 1;
      return groceryService.newId;
    }

  };


  groceryService.save = function(entry){

    entry.id = groceryService.getNewId();

    groceryService.groceryItems.push(entry);

  };

  return groceryService;


});


app.controller("HomeController", ["$scope","GroceryService", function"($scope, GroceryService) {

  $scope.groceryItems = GroceryService.groceryItems;

}]);

app.controller("GroceryListItemController", ["$scope","$routeParams","$location","GroceryService", function($scope,$routeParams,$location,GroceryService) {

  if(!$routeParams.id){
    $scope.groceryItem = { id:0, completed:false, itemName: "", date: new Date() };
    }else{
      $scope.groceryItem = GroceryService.findById(parseInt($routeParams.Id));

    }

  //$scope.groceryItems = GroceryService.groceryItems;

  //$scope.rp ="Route Parameter Values:" + $routeParams.id;

 // $scope.groceryItem ={ id:7,completed:true, itemName: "cheese",date: new Date() }

  $scope.save = function(){
    GroceryService.save( $scope.groceryItem );
    $location.path("/");
  };

  //console.log($scope.groceryItems);

}]);
```

**groceryList.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <a href="#!/addItem" style="margin-bottom: 10px:" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Grocery Item </a>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in groceryItems | orderBy: 'date'" class="list-group-item text-center clearfix">
      <span style="font-weight: bold">{{item.itemName | uppercase}}</span>
      <a href="#!/addItem/edit/{{item.id}}" class="btn btn-nm btn-default pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**addItem.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Add Item Below</h1>
        </div>
<form name="groceryForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder ="Grocery Item" ng-model="groceryItem.itemName">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn lg btn-block" ng-click="save()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></span>
            Save
        </button>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="#/" class="btn btn-default btn lg btn-block">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

After running index.html on a web server, the output in the browser is :

Grocery List

However, the list of grocery items are not displayed along with "Grocery List"

The various items are supposed to be displayed on the same page.

Are the brackets and all correct?

Please help!!!

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

You need a state to be defined for listing out the grocery as

```
 .when("/grocery", {
      templateUrl: "groceryList.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })
```

and change the template as

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#grocery">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
          </span> Grocery List
</a>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gT81189tI3qTbbnBCHlu?p=info)**

Comment: this is url change, isnt it?

Comment: did you check the demo attached

Comment: I have checked the demo attached and your demo isnt showing the boostrap functionalities, as you dont have the scripts loaded in. However i have added

Comment: .when("/grocery", {
      templateUrl: "groceryList.html",
      controller: "HomeController"
    })     has been added along with                                                                                              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#grocery">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-apple" style="color: #5bdb46">
          </span> Grocery List
</a> but sadly no change has occurred. What else can i do? @Sajeetharan.

Comment: dude dont expect every single feature to be working, just i have provided the demo for the issue you asked

Comment: @Sajeetharan - check this demo: [https://plnkr.co/edit/rSby36xtnndkCrgS3zNN?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/rSby36xtnndkCrgS3zNN) I forked from your demo and replaced `/grocery` to `/` again and it's working. Can you explain why it was necessary making this change to url structure?